# How to add contents of this stream into a linked list?

Tags: java, csv

I need to read from a CSV file and add the contents into a linked list, so that I can search for a certain bit of data. At the moment the results of the CSV are fed into a stream, but I don't know how to put this into a linked list. My code is as follows:

```
    String fileName = "Catalogue.csv";
    LinkedList<String>catalogue = new LinkedList();

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

                stream.forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You're currently printing the elements, why can't you add them to the list instead of printing?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-. Why a linked list? You like your code slower than it could be?

Comment: If you need to find data, you don't need to collect the whole contents of the stream into a list. You can just search directly on the stream

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following one liner should work:

```
catalogue = stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

You can refer to the `Collectors` doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) and `LinkedList` doc here. As mentioned in the comments above, I wouldn't advice you to unnecessarily use `LinkedList` in this case though as it will make your code that follows a little slower.

Comment: That creates a list, and then a copy of the list. It's unnecessarily inefficient. You can create a linked list directly with stream.colect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))

Comment: @JBNizet Totally forgot that you can do that as well.. Thanks for reminding. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need exactly `LinkedList`, you can just collect your stream:

```
stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Or, if list is already created:

```
stream.forEach(catalogue::add);
```